# Only draw closePath() line

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

So I'm trying to draw a polygon using the arc function. I know there are better ways to draw a polygon but I'm going to use this functionality to plot points within later on.

I've got the shape drawn no problem, however, the arc path is visible so I was wondering if there is just a simple way to remove it from the path. I've tried a couple of things and I haven't found anything online.

Failing this, would there be a way to store the current position before the arc is drawn and use this position to create the line from the endpoint instead?

```
start = 0;
inc = 360 / sides;

con.strokeStyle = 'rgb(73, 150, 210)';
con.lineWidth = 8;

for(i = 1; i <= sides; i++){
  end = inc * i;
  con.beginPath();
  con.arc(500, 500, 500, toRadians(start), toRadians(end));
  con.closePath();
  con.stroke();
  start = end;
}
```

[image: Current result]

Edit: Someone recommended another post about transparency, I don't see anything in that post about separating closePath from the actual path itself. Maybe I missed something since that post is fairly long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this modified approach?

```js
const con = canvas.getContext("2d");
const sides = 10;

con.strokeStyle = 'rgb(73, 150, 210)';
con.lineWidth = 1;

con.beginPath();

// for loop from i=0 to i = sides+1
// j is the angle we are currently at
// use sin & cos aggregate methods to get the positions on 2d grid
for (let i = 0, j=2 * Math.PI / sides; i <= sides+1; i++, j = i * 2 * Math.PI / sides)
  con.lineTo(50 + 50 * Math.cos(j), 50 + 50 * Math.sin(j));
con.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>
```